# Why does applemac inputenc not work anymore for umlauts?

Tags: texshop, input-encodings

In order to type umlauts in latex (with Texshop) like e.g. 'ä' I used to be able to just add

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
```

at the beginning of my `.tex` file and I'd be able to compile umlauts.

Now I tried the same and it does not work. I get

```
Latex Error: Command \textperthousand unavailable in encoding OT1.
```

I am running OS X 10.9.5 with Texshop 3.36.2.

And I am 100% sure that the last time I did this it worked.

I'm asking this question just because I want to know why it doesn't work anymore, what has changed. It's not a problem to me, I know at least two work arounds.

Thanks in advance for lifting the mystery. : )

PS: I wanted to check the file encoding and change it if necessary but I couldn't work out how to do that in Texshop.

Comment: are you sure your editor is still saving files in the legacy apple encoding and hasn't been updated to default to a standard encoding such as UTF-8? (also but unrelated you should not be using OT1 fonts if using accented characters so you want `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know, like I said: I wanted to check the file encoding and change it if necessary but I couldn't work out how to do that in Texshop. But if the encoding were UTF-8 then `\usepackage[utf-8]{inputenc}` should have worked but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\textperthousand` has slot 228 in input encoding `applemac`. Other encodings, which use `ä` at this place, are `latin1`, `latin2`, `latin3`, `latin4`, `latin5`, `latin9`, `latin10`, `decmulti`, `ansinew`, `cp1250`, `cp1252`, `cp1257`.

Probably your file got re-encoded with `latin1` or `latin9` (with Euro), `ansinew` (with Windows extensions).

Package `selinput` helps in choosing the encoding, if the encoding is not known to the user:

```
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
  adieresis=ä,
  germandbls=ß,
  % ...
}
```